# Mapbox iOS Search by Attributes or Features

Tags: ios, search, mapbox

I have a common use case that I haven't found documentation or examples on. I've added data to my iOS Mapbox app via TileSets in MapBox Studio. I'd like to simply implement a UISearch function on the data in that Tileset using some attribute. For example, I've added a TileSet with 100 different roads in some county in Alaska, and I'd like the user to be able to search for a specific road in the search bar. This seems like it should be easier than I am making it, but I've been working on it for weeks. The original data is geoJSON but I'd like it to be hosted in MapBox Studio so I can update the data without needing to update the app once its released.

Note that this is different than the visibleFeatures function which returns MGLFeatures by location or Rect. I really just need to get all features list from a layer so I can populate it in the UISearch functionality.

Any suggestions? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update after talking with Mapbox customer support and folks familiar with how to do this.

Two ways to query features in map:
(1) use the MapBox visibleFeaturesAt() function for features within the rendered map: lots of documentation on this. But this is limited in that it only returns features nearby to your mapview camera. If you want to do a big global search, can't rely on this. So second option is
(2) for global searches, transition to using an external database outside of mapbox. Mapbox isn't designed to be searched up globally for features like this question. If you want to search an attribute that is unrelated map-wise to current view, start using a back-end database like FireBase.